# get a jsp variable in an included jsp page

Tags: javascript, html, jsp, include

I am working on a project and I need to be able to access a variable from an included jsp page. Each of my jsp pages include the header, footer and a variable like so;

```
<jsp:include page="header.jsp"></jsp:include>
<c:set var="myVariable" value="hello" />

<!-- content -->

<jsp:include page="footer.jsp"></jsp:include>
```

I have written a javascript function which uses this variable, for now lets just say:

```
console.log( '<c:out value="${myVariable}"/>' );
```

Now when this line is ***beneath*** the footer include page it works perfectly. However, I do not want to have my javascript code at the bottom of every page - it quickly becomes unmanageable and messy. Is there a way I can access this variable in the same way, but from ***within*** the footer.jsp page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try changing scope

```
<c:set var="myVariable" value="hello" scope="session"/>
```

Comment: Super, I never knew about this attribute. Cheers

Comment: you may also use request as in scope="request" http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16619015/passing-data-to-jspinclude-via-cset