# How do I invoke a static method in EL

Tags: jsp, el, static-methods

Hi I'm maintaining some legacy JSP code and I need to be able to do some conditional rendering like

```
<c:if test="${SomeClass.staticMethod(obj.getUrl())}">
    <td> ... </td>
</c:if>
```

However I'm getting syntax error at position 19, encountered '(', expected '}', I think the test attribute doesn't like the fact that a function is being called in there?

How do I conditionally render some html in a JSP based on the return value of a function?

Comment: [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25893913/how-to-pass-java-variables-from-scriptlets-to-cwhen-expression-in-jstl) should help.

Comment: @AndrewS Is there a way to conditionally render without having to write to these various scopes? Or is that just a fundamental limitation of JSPs

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6395621/how-to-call-a-static-method-in-jsp-el