# How does EL #{bean.id} call managed bean method bean.getId()

Tags: jsf, el, getter

I do not really understand how getter and setter work althougth it is a basic concept. I have the following code, how is the attribute `id` sent to Managed Bean? Is it captured by getter method?

My facelet

```
<p:inputText id="id" value="#{bean.id}">
```

My managed bean

```
private String id;

public void setId(String id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public String getId() {
      return id;
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1568091/why-use-getters-and-setters

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The call of getter and setter methods by `#{}` expressions is not part of JSF but [Expression Language](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/el/info) (most known as EL). JSF takes advantage of EL to bind the data of the HTML components to the fields of a bean through proper getters and setters. This is:

- If the bean exists, Expression Language will execute the proper getter of the registered bean in the proper scope.
- If client performs a form submission or an ajax request, then the components that are sent to the server (usually all the components in the `<h:form>`, in case of ajax requests you can state which components to send to the server) will contain a new value, and this value will be set to the field with the proper setter method.

For example, you have a `SayHelloBean` which belongs to request scope:

```
@RequestScoped
@ManagedBean
public class LoginBean {
    private String name;
    //proper getter
    public String getName() {
        return this.name;
    }
    //proper setter
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

And these 2 facelets pages (since it's an example I avoid declaring `<html>`, `<h:head>`, `<h:body>` and other elements, just focusing on the relevant code)

Page1.xhtml:

```html
<h:form>
    Please tell me your name
    <h:inputText value="#{loginBean.name}" />
    <h:commandButton action="page2" />
</h:form>
```

Page2.xhtml:

```html
Hello #{loginBean.name}
```

This is what happens behind the scenes:

1. When Page1.xhtml is loaded, a new instance of `LoginBean`, which we may call `loginBean`, will be created by JSF and registered into JSP request scope.  Since the value of `<h:inputText />` is bound to `LoginBean#name` (which is read as *the field `name` of `LoginBean` class*), then EL will display the value of `loginBean#name` (which is read as *the field `name` of instance `loginBean`*), and since that is not initialized, EL will display `null`, as an empty string.
2. When you submit the form of Page1.xhtml, since `LoginBean` is `@RequestScoped` then JSF will create a new instance of `LoginBean`, which we may call it `loginBean2` (adding `2` in the end because this instance is totally different from the `loginBean` previously created) and will register it in JSP request scope. Since the value of `<h:inputText />` is bound to `LoginBean#name`, JSF will validate and set the data by calling the proper setter. This will make `loginBean2#name` have the value of the `<input type="text">` that was rendered by `<h:inputText/>`.
3. At last, JSF will make sure to navigate to Page2.xhtml through forward, where when processing it, it will find `#{loginBean.name}` and EL will check for the value of `loginBean2#name` and replace it.

The steps explained here are a very small explanation (and with lot of elements not explained) of the JSF lifecycle and how JSF uses getters and setters.

More info:

- [How to pass parameter to jsp:include via c:set? What are the scopes of the variables in JSP?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16619015/1065197)
- [How to choose the right bean scope?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7031885/1065197)
- [The Lifecycle of a JavaServer Faces Application](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/bnaqq.html)
- [Differences between Forward and Redirect](http://javarevisited.blogspot.com/2011/09/sendredirect-forward-jsp-servlet.html)

---

Additional note: since you're learning JSF, avoid putting any business logic code in getters/setters. This is greatly explained here: [Why JSF calls getters multiple times](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2090033/1065197)

Comment: Nicely explained. But how will I initialise a inputtext(mentioned in your case) with a value (setting default is a different matter, I am not asking that) from the database. If i do it (name initialising to someDataBaseValue()) with PostContruct, well it works then. But i failed to understand why this not works inside a contructor.

Comment: @ShirgillAnsari while I did some debug on my managed bean constructors, I noticed that JSF didn't call them at all but the `@PostConstruct` method does (after injecting elements, if any). I don't know the exact details (and it's 1 am where I live) but I can do the research, and I believe BalusC has covered this topic on a blog post or here in StackOverflow. I'll let you know if I find info on the subject.

Comment: Thank you for your response. It's posted as a separate question. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27540573/how-to-initialize-inputtextfield-with-a-value-from-database-on-runtime-without-t

Comment: Sorry to disturb you. But even after considerable research effort, it yielded no fruitful result to me.

Answer (score 1):

Whenever you use something like

```
#{someBean.someField}
```

the EL looks for a someBean.getSomeField() or someBean.setSomeField(...) method, depending on whether you're reading that field or writing in it (which can easily be inferred from the context). JSF never accesses a field directly (i.e without making use of its getter or setter). Try deleting the getter and setter of a given field and you'll see it won't work.